# Set $U \subset (0,\infty) \forall x \in U \space\forall 1\neq n\in \mathbb N \space \implies x^n \notin U $ Find the maximal U cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define set $U \subset (0,\infty) \forall x \in U \space\forall 1\neq n\in \mathbb N \space \implies x^n \notin U $

Find the maximal U cardinality.

I know there are maximal U (Zorn's lemma), but i do not know how to find $|U|$.

I want to suppose $|U|=\aleph_0$ and proof there is no surjective function from $\mathbb N \to U$.

I have no idea how to deal with it.

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: The notation "$\forall 1\neq n\in \Bbb N (\phi(n))$" is a bit nonstandard, I would write this as $\forall n\in\Bbb N(n\neq 1\to \phi(n))$ instead.

Comment: @Vsotvep What is $(\phi(n))$ ?

Comment: $\phi$ is a formula. In your case, this would be $x^n\notin U$

Comment: To be more precise: your formula reads out loud as "for all $x$ in $U$ and for all $1$ that are not equal to $n$ in $\Bbb N$ implies that $x^n$ is not in $U$". It doesn't make much sense. Instead, you should write $\forall x\in U\forall n\in\Bbb N(n\neq 1 \implies x^n\notin U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a hint:

Let $U\subseteq(0,\infty)$ be maximal such that $\forall x\in U\forall n\in\Bbb N(n\neq 1\implies x^n\notin U)$

1. For any $x\in(0,\infty)$ the set $A_x=\{x^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is countable.
2. If $y\in (0,\infty)$, then there is some $x\in U$ such that $y\in A_x$ (why?). Therefore $(0,\infty)=\bigcup_{x\in U}\big(A_x\cap (0,\infty)\big)$.

Can you combine 1. and 2. to find the cardinality of a maximal $U$?

Comment: If $y\in (0,\infty)$ , then there is some $x \in U$ such that $y\in A_{x}$ since ,if there is no $y$ like that then $U$ is not maximal set , and we can take $U \cup \left\{ y\right\}$,contradiction.

Then
$\mathfrak{c}=|(0,\infty)|=|\bigcup_{x\in U}\big(A_x\cap (0,\infty)\big)|=|A_x\cdot U| = |A_x| \cdot |U|=\aleph_0\cdot|U| \implies |U|=\aleph $, is it correct ?

Comment: @erez Yes, that's correct, although it is highly unusual to use **both** $\mathfrak c$ and $\aleph$ to denote $|\mathbb R|$ in the same line.